# In ckeditor source view, all characters changed to HTML code

Tags: ckeditor

For some reason, in my application, when I click on the "View Source" button of ckeditor, all the characters changed to HTML codes, for example "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" changed to `"&#76;&#111;&#114;&#101;&#109; &#105;&#112;&#115;&#117;&#109; &#100;&#111;&#108;&#111;&#114; &#115;&#105;&#116; &#97;&#109;&#101;&#116;"`

This makes it impossible to modify the content by editing the HTML code, and also, some symbols will disappeared after saved.

Does anyone knows why ?

Comment: You need to show us your config. This is not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Just quite simple configuration, and the fact is, this works fine before, I didn't change any configuration, but I do changed some code for ckeditor, I added one button there, but I didn't see there's anything connected, because I just added that button with the official way, only "added" code&folder, didn't modify any existing codes. So I just hope someone who knows what might cause this problem.

Comment: Strange. I think that you need to prepare a sample that will show this issue. Otherwise, we won't be able to help you. And make sure that it is not a backend issue - that correct data is loaded.

Comment: I tried to backup my current codes of ckeditor, and install the newest version, everything is fine now. Then next, I will try to put my modified codes from backup to the newest version one by one, and try to find out what caused the problem, I will update this thread after I got an answer, thx Reinmar!